# multiple openvpn tunnels on same port

Tags: openvpn

I would like to connect multiple servers/subnets to a central server.  Can i configure multiple openvpn instances with separate tun interfaces on the central server all on the default port udp/1194 ?

How will the central server match the incoming traffic to the specific tunnel?

Can this be done using PSK keys ?